# How to enable HTML in WP input field?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, input, tags

How can I enable HTML in a string that comes from the WP backend?
What I am after is that users can enter HTML in the backend inputfield and when submitted, the HTML is rendered as HTML, for example the `<br>` tag works to break the line.

Am a starter with PHP. Below what I have got so far...
First setting up the array with the tags that are allowed.
Then the PHP lines to readout the input field 'bloginfo'.

```
<?php 

$allowed_html = array(
     'a' => array(
          'href' => array(),
          'title' => array(),
     ),
     'br' => array(),
     'em' => array(),
     'strong' => array(),
);

echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name') ); ?>
  <div id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description', $allowed_html ); ?></div>
         </div>
```

Comment: This presents a significant security hole. Just sayin'.

Comment: ^ Never trust a user :)
Best would be to use something like markup, or stackoverflow syntax.